# Raspberry Pi: Playing multiple video files in mkfifo pipe

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspbian, omxplayer

I have 2 files, test.mp4 and test2.mp4 that I want to play concurrently with no noticeable break in the middle. Currently I'm using

```
mkfifo test
cat test.mp4 > test &
cat test2.mp4 > test &
omxplayer test
```

However, when I do this, omxplayer just returns data and doesn't play the file. But if I just put a single file into the pipe, omxplayer shows it normally. I've also tried using the copy command in ffmpeg, and that also just returns data, doesn't play the file.

I understand that I can just concatenate the 2 files together, but that will not work for my purposes, because I will need to be able to feed files to the pipe while omxplayer is running

Answer (score 0):

Your are running both cats in the background which means the data will be interleaved in a random way and omxplayer is unlikely to understand it.

Your script should be:

```
mkfifo test
cat test.mp4 test2.mp4 > test &
omxplayer test
```

But, even this will not suit your needs because as soon as the `cat` finishes omxplayer will think its the end of the input and will stop.

You need something like this:

```
sendvideo() {
  #
  # Code to select file to send
  #
  cat test.mp4
  #
  # Code to select file to send
  #
  cat test2.mp4
  #
  # Loop to select files
  #
  while [ some condition ]; do
    cat somefile
  done
}
# Starts here
mkfifo test
sendvideo > test &
omxplayer test
```

Comment: Doing this only plays the first file in the fifo